# calling the function, checking for palindromes in a range

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a function, which recursively checks for palindromes in a given range. The range is sent to "is_palindrome_multi", which then calls "is_palindrome". 
However, it doesn't work with numbers higher then 10, so the limiting step seems to be:

> elif data[0]==data[-1]:

statement. Why it doesn't return true for the numbers like 11, 22 and so on? I will be grateful for explanation.

```
def is_palindorme_multi(beg, end):
    for i in range(beg, end):
        i = str(i)
        if is_palindrome(i) == True:
            print "Palindrome"
        else:
            print "Not palindrome"


def is_palindrome(data):    
    print data,
    if len(data)==1 or len(data)==0:
        return True
    elif data[0]==data[-1]:
        is_palindrome(data[1:-1])
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're trying to use recursion?

Comment: no, I know there are better solutions for this. I just couldn't conquer this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not returning the result of the recursive call.

Change your `elif`:

```
elif data[0]==data[-1]:
    is_palindrome(data[1:-1])
```

to:

```
elif data[0]==data[-1]:
    return is_palindrome(data[1:-1])
```

---

However, I would simply change your `is_palindrome` method to:

```
def is_palindrome(data): 
    return data == data[::-1]
```

Really, no need to use recursion here.

Comment: that works great! Can you explain it to me, please? Why it didn't work without returning?

Comment: @mik.ro. If you don't return the value of method call, the value returned is `None`, which is propagated down the stack trace to the first method call. So the final value that is returned is `None`. You should learn about *recursion* in general.